# On scroll add more json data in listView

Tags: android, json, listview, scrollview, endlessadapter

I made one `ListView` with image and text. I am able to parse *json data* in the ListView. But my requirenment is  to **load 10 rows of Json data**, then at the bottom have a **load more.** to get the next 10, etc etc.
Suggest me if anyone knows the solution using json please...

- Here is my code for **Adapter.java**

  ```
  public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      private Activity activity;
      private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
      public ImageLoader imageLoader;

      public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
          activity = a;
          data=d;
          inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
      }

      public int getCount() {
          return data.size();
      }

      public Object getItem(int position) {
          return position;
      }

      public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
      }

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View vi=convertView;
          if(convertView==null)
              vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

          TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
          TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
          TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
          ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
          ImageView thumb_image1=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);// thumb image

          HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
          song = data.get(position);

          // Setting all values in listview
          title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.USER_NAME));
          artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
          duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
          imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);

          imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL1), thumb_image1);
          return vi;
      }
  }
  ```
- Here is the code of **MainActivity.java**

  ```
  public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
      // All static variables
      static final String URL = XXXX.json;
      //private static String URL;
      // XML node keys
      static final String KEY_SONG = "review_full"; // parent node
      static final String KEY_ID = "activity_id";
      static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
      static final String KEY_ARTIST = "review_small";
      static final String KEY_DURATION = "time";
      static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb";
      static final String KEY_THUMB_URL1 = "photo";
      String type;
      String user_name1;
      String thumbnail;
      String subscriber_name;
      String review_full;
      String status;
      String photo;
      ListView list;
      String review_small;
      LazyAdapter adapter;


      String[] image;
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
      public  String image1=null;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);

          //Intent intent1 = getIntent();
          //String easyPuzzle = intent1.getExtras().getString("Id");  
          //URL=URL0+easyPuzzle;
          songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
          JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
          JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);


          try{
              Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before json1 try2");
              JSONArray activities = json.getJSONArray("activities");
              Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "after activiti");

              for (int i = 0; i < activities.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject c = activities.getJSONObject(i);
                  image=new String[2];
                  Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "inside for loop");
                  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                  //checking type content
                  type=c.getString("type");

                  if(type.contains("user")){
                      user_name1=c.getString( USER_NAME);
                      thumbnail=c.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                      map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  thumbnail);

                      map.put(USER_NAME, user_name1+" "+"joined etable community");
                      map.put(KEY_DURATION,  c.getString( KEY_DURATION));
                      //  map.put(KEY_ARTIST,null);

                  }else if(type.contains("checkin")){
                      user_name1=c.getString( USER_NAME);
                      subscriber_name=c.getString("subscriber_name");
                      thumbnail=c.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                      photo=c.getString("photo");

                      if(photo.contains("False")){
                          image1="False";
                          map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL1, image1);
                      }else{

                          image = photo.split("image=");
                          image1=image[1];
                          map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL1, image1);

                      }

                      map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  thumbnail);
                      map.put(USER_NAME, user_name1+" "+"was spotted at"+" "+subscriber_name);
                      map.put(KEY_DURATION,  c.getString( KEY_DURATION));
                      //  map.put(KEY_ARTIST,null);

                  }else if(type.contains("favorite")){
                      subscriber_name=c.getString("subscriber_name");
                      user_name1=c.getString( USER_NAME);
                      thumbnail=c.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);

                      map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  thumbnail);
                      map.put(USER_NAME, user_name1+" "+"favorited"+" "+subscriber_name);
                      map.put(KEY_DURATION,  c.getString( KEY_DURATION));
                      //map.put(KEY_ARTIST,null);

                  }else if(type.contains("review")){
                      subscriber_name=c.getString("subscriber_name");
                      user_name1=c.getString( USER_NAME);
                      review_small=c.getString("review_small");
                      review_full=c.getString("review_full");

                      thumbnail=c.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                      map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  thumbnail);
                      map.put(USER_NAME, user_name1+" "+"wrote a review for"+" "+subscriber_name);
                      map.put(KEY_DURATION,  c.getString( KEY_DURATION));
                      map.put(KEY_ARTIST,review_small);
                      map.put(KEY_SONG,review_full);

                  }else if(type.contains("status")){
                      user_name1=c.getString( USER_NAME);
                      status=c.getString("full_status");

                      thumbnail=c.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                      map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  thumbnail);
                      map.put(USER_NAME, user_name1+" "+"says\n"+" "+status);
                      map.put(KEY_DURATION,  c.getString( KEY_DURATION));
                      //map.put(KEY_ARTIST,null);

                  }else{
                      user_name1=c.getString( USER_NAME);
                      map.put(USER_NAME, user_name1+" "+"some problem");
                      //map.put(KEY_ARTIST,null);
                  }

                  // adding HashList to ArrayList
                  songsList.add(map);

              }}catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

          // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
          adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
          list.setAdapter(adapter);
          list.invalidateViews();

          // Click event for single list row
          list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                      int position, long id) {
                  list.invalidateViews();
                  Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "start click");
                  HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);

                  Intent in = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, LargeView.class);
                  in.putExtra("text", map.get(USER_NAME));
                  in.putExtra("image", map.get(KEY_THUMB_URL));
                  in.putExtra("review", map.get(KEY_SONG));

                  Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "inside profile33");

                  startActivity(in);
                  Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", USER_NAME);

              }
          });
      }

  }
  ```